# Is there a way to modify styles to an external component library without specifying the default class names or using !important?

Tags: css, reactjs, less, styling

My client is using AntDesign, and we have a layout that has a search input in it, now in AntDesign, the Input.Search component comes packaged with a button included in it.

The issue is that the layout side bar, and the search input, share a class, so when they are both inside the layout, it applies a class to my search input that makes the icon inside the button offset.

[image: AntDesign Search Input image]

I can directly manipulate this using the class name `.ant-btn .anticon`,
however this is bad practice because if the class name is updated this will silently fail, as well as may conflict with consistent site wide styling.

Is there a way to update this button and its styles without directly overriding the default class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a fairly simple solution with styled-components which allows me to create a component that looks like this:

[image]
Using the `&&&` will allow me to override the styles without directly using the class names or using `!important`

More information can be found using here: [LESS - Multiple &](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/less/multiple.htm)